# Python: Remove First Character of each Word in String

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to figure out how to remove the first character of a words in a string.

My program reads in a string.

Suppose the input is :

> this is demo

My intention is to remove the first character of each word of the string, that is
`tid`, leaving `his s emo`.

I have tried

1. Using a `for loop` and traversing the string
2. Checking for **space** in the string using `isspace() function.`
3. Storing the index of the letter which is encountered after the
   space, `i = char + 1,`   where char is the index of space.
4. Then, trying to remove the empty space using `str_replaced = str[i:].`

But it removed the entire string except the last one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

List comprehensions is your friend. This is the most basic version, in just one line

```
str = "this is demo";
print " ".join([x[1:] for x in str.split(" ")]);

output:   
his s emo
```

Answer (score 4):

In case the input string can have not only spaces, but also newlines or tabs, I'd use [regex](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html).

```
In [1]: inp = '''Suppose we have a
   ...: multiline input...'''

In [2]: import re

In [3]: print re.sub(r'(?<=\b)\w', '', inp)
uppose e ave 
ultiline nput...
```

Comment: thanks a lot..that was great..i never thought that we need to use REGEX here

Comment: @user1465544 Glad to help, consider [accepting the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/181223) if it resolved your problem. Also, if there's no need in preserving correct whitespace or only plain spaces can occur, then regex is not necessary and you can use `str.split()` method.

Comment: can you please explain me the steps it would do? i am learning this language actually

Comment: @user1465544 Something like `' '.join(word[1:] for word in inp.split())`.

Comment: ok..thanks a lot..but i have found a catch here..suppose my input is Here's my string..then this method actually prints ere' my sting..means, the 's is getting ommited..

Comment: Yeah, that happens because `'` is not considered a word character. You can work around this with `print re.sub(r'(?<!\w|\')\w', '', inp)`. Also the `join` option works OK for your example.

Comment: it has worked..thanks a lot for the help..i would like to know what are the good books available for python..presently, i am using the website learn python the hard way to learn..thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

You can simply using python comprehension

```
str = 'this is demo'
mstr = ' '.join([s[1:] for s in str.split(' ')])
```

then `mstr` variable will contains these values `'his s emo'`

Answer (score 0):

This method is a bit long, but easy to understand. The flag variable stores if the character is a space. If it is, the next letter must be removed

```
s = "alpha beta charlie"
t = ""
flag = 0
for x in range(1,len(s)):
    if(flag==0):
         t+=s[x]
    else:
        flag = 0
    if(s[x]==" "):
        flag = 1
print(t)

output
lpha eta harlie
```